# fade effect on easyslider 1.7?

Tags: javascript, fade, effect, easyslider

Can there be a fade effect (as seen on www.outspark.com) instead of a slider effect on EasySlider 1.7?  I want the slider images to fade instead of slide.

I can't past the javascript code here but here's the paste: http://pastebin.com/B8j7wKX9

Answer (score 2):

look for this line

```
if(!options.vertical) {
                    p = (t*w*-1);
                    $("ul",obj).animate(
                        { marginLeft: p }, 
                        { queue:false, duration:speed, complete:adjust }
                    );              
                }
```

and change it for

```
if(!options.vertical) {
                    p = (t*w*-1);
                    $("ul",obj).animate(
                        { opacity: 0 }, 
                        { queue:false, duration:'slow', complete:adjust }
                    );  
}
```

then look for this line

```
if(!options.vertical) {
                $("ul",obj).css("margin-left",(t*w*-1));
            }
```

and change it for

```
if(!options.vertical) {
                $("ul",obj).css("margin-left",(t*w*-1));
                $("ul",obj).animate(
                        { opacity: 1 }, 
                        { queue:false, duration:'slow'}
                    );  
            }
```

I hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

EasySlider doesn't include fading, but there's a modified version of it that does: http://bogojoker.com/easySlide/

Try that.